# Reducing nested for loops in Dart

Tags: for-loop, dart

I'm trying to append days to an existing month in a calendar. I have a object called "Calendar" which has a list of "CalendarMonths" and each month had a list of "CalandarDays". The below code works to append a day to a existing month but I don't like the nested for loops... I need some help and advice, is there a function or a algorithm that can reduce my issue?

```
for (var month in calendar.months) {
  CalendarMonth calendarMonth = getExistingCalendarMonth(month, oldCalendar);
  if (CalendarMonth != null) {
    for (var day in month.days) {
      CalendarDay calendarDay = getExistingCalendarDay(day, calendarMonth);
      if (calendarDay != null) {
        for (var item in day.calendarItems) {
          calendarDay.calendarItems.add(item);
        }
      } else {
        calendarMonth.days.add(day);
      }
    }
  } else {
    oldCalendar.months.add(month);
  }
}

CalendarMonth getExistingCalendarMonth(CalendarMonth month, Calendar old) {
for (var calendarMonth in old.months) {
  if (calendarMonth.title == month.title) {
    return calendarMonth;
  }
}
return null;}

CalendarDay getExistingCalendarDay(CalendarDay day, CalendarMonth old) {
for (var calendarDay in old.days) {
  if (calendarDay.day == day.day) {
    return calendarDay;
  }
}
return null;}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a DartPad so it's easier to reproduce and test this ?

Comment: What is the difference between `calendar` and `oldCalendar` and why do you seem to be actively maintaining both?

Comment: @Abion47 I guess he wants to translate some calendar into another calendar.

Comment: @Dave why do you want to reduce the nested for loops?

Comment: @paladin Then the `oldCalendar.months.add` bit is an odd choice.

Comment: @Abion47 Calendar is the new fetched data from the server, if the month and day already exists in the oldCalendar then the items will be appended to this "oldCalendar" if the month doesn't exists then the month with days and items will be directly added to the oldCalendar.. maybe the name is a bit misleading.

Comment: @paladin I was wondering if there is some kind of a method to recude the nested for loops, just curios that's all.

Comment: @Steve Nosse How can I create one?

Comment: What language are you using? You have tags for java, c#, and dart. Please don't language-spam.

Comment: If you are constantly looking up values in lists by something other than their index, that's a good sign that you should be using maps instead.

Comment: Aaah maps, thats new for me. Do you have a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main crux of your problem seems to have come from the fact that you have chosen to represent your calendar's months and days as lists, forcing you to iterate over the entire list to find the object with a particular value. When you are trying to find an element in a list by something other than its index in that list, you are using the wrong data structure for the job.

What you need to use is a `Map`. This data structure has a different name in a lot of places like `HashMap`, `HashTable`, `Record`, or `Dictionary` (all of which have subtly different implications as to how they are used, but they are interchangeable in the general case). The idea is that you store data in a table using a key, and later you can reference that data in constant time by using that key. For example:

```dart
Map<String, int> map = {
  'a': 123,
  'b': 456,
  'c': 789,
};
print(map['b']);
// Output: 456
```

I create a map that has a key type of `String` and a value type of `int`, which means I am storing a bunch of integers in the map and using string values to reference them. After that, I am using the same index notation that lists use to retrieve the data, but instead of supplying an integer index, I am using a string key and telling the map to give me the data stored under that key. In this case, I am pulling the value stored in the key "b" which is the integer value `456`.

In your case, your `Calendar` class defines `months` as a list of objects with each object storing its name and another list of `days`. Instead, use a map for `months` which you can then use with the name of that month to get the month directly:

```dart
class Calendar {
  ...
  final months = <String, CalendarMonth>{};
}

class CalendarMonth {
  ...
  final String title;
  final days = <int, CalendarDay>{};
}

class CalendarDay {
  ...
  final int monthIndex;
  final calendarItems = <CalendarItem>[];
}
```

Here I am using the shorthand syntax that Dart has for creating a map `<String, CalendarMonth>{}` which means am empty map with key type `String` and value type `CalendarMonth`. I am also using an `int` as the key for `CalendarMonth.days` which might seem odd since using an integer key seems like using a list with extra steps, but the key difference here is that the integer keys for a map don't need to represent indices that exist in a list and therefore can be any integer you want. (They don't even need to be continuous.)

Now you can refactor your insertion loops like this:

```dart
for (var month in calendar.months.values) {
  CalendarMonth calendarMonth = oldCalendar.months[month.title];
  if (CalendarMonth != null) {
    for (var day in month.days.values) {
      CalendarDay calendarDay = calendarMonth.days[day.monthIndex];
      if (calendarDay != null) {
        calendarDay.calendarItems.addAll(dat.calendarItems);
      } else {
        calendarMonth.days[day.monthIndex] = day;
      }
    }
  } else {
    oldCalendar.months[month.title] = month;
  }
}
```

Note that since you are iterating over the values in the new months and days, you can't get away from using for loops entirely (since the whole concept of iteration is what loops were designed for). If you wanted, you could clean this up by moving the logic into the `Calendar`, `CalendarMonth`, and `CalendarDay` classes themselves:

```dart
class Calendar {
  ...
  
  void merge(Calendar other) {
    for (var month in other.months.values) {
      if (months.containsKey(month.title)) {
        months[monthTitle].merge(month);
      } else {
        months[monthTitle] = month;
      }
    }
  }
}

class CalendarMonth {
  ...

  void merge(CalendarMonth other) {
    for (var day in other.days.values) {
      if (days.containsKey(day.monthIndex)) {
        days[day.monthIndex].merge(day);
      } else {
        days[day.monthIndex] = day;
      }
    }
  }
}

class CalendarDay {
  ...

  void merge(CalendarDay other) {
    calendarItems.addAll(other.calendarItems);
  }
}
```

Which would make your original code look like this:

```dart
oldCalendar.merge(calendar);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this helps me a lot! Maps are very interesting and I'm gonna try this one out!